# JSON can not be deserialized

Tags: c#, json, httpclient

I have made an API request which fetches data from an API. When I look at the JSON I get, it contains the data I need. However, when I try to deserialize the JSON, it does not work.

**JSON:**

```
{
   "get":"leagues",
   "parameters":[
      
   ],
   "errors":[
      
   ],
   "results":960,
   "paging":{
      "current":1,
      "total":1
   },
   "response":[
      {
         "league":{
            "id":4,
            "name":"Euro Championship",
            "type":"Cup",
            "logo":"https:\/\/media-3.api-sports.io\/football\/leagues\/4.png"
         },
         "country":{
            "name":"World",
            "code":null,
            "flag":null
         },
         "seasons":[
            {
               "year":2008,
               "start":"2008-06-07",
               "end":"2008-06-29",
               "current":false,
               "coverage":{
                  "fixtures":{
                     "events":true,
                     "lineups":true,
                     "statistics_fixtures":false,
                     "statistics_players":false
                  },
                  "standings":false,
                  "players":false,
                  "top_scorers":false,
                  "top_assists":false,
                  "top_cards":false,
                  "injuries":false,
                  "predictions":true,
                  "odds":false
               }
            },
            {
               "year":2012,
               "start":"2012-06-08",
               "end":"2012-07-01",
               "current":false,
               "coverage":{
                  "fixtures":{
                     "events":true,
                     "lineups":true,
                     "statistics_fixtures":false,
                     "statistics_players":false
                  },
                  "standings":false,
                  "players":false,
                  "top_scorers":false,
                  "top_assists":false,
                  "top_cards":false,
                  "injuries":false,
                  "predictions":true,
                  "odds":false
               }
            },
            {
               "year":2016,
               "start":"2016-06-10",
               "end":"2016-07-10",
               "current":false,
               "coverage":{
                  "fixtures":{
                     "events":true,
                     "lineups":true,
                     "statistics_fixtures":true,
                     "statistics_players":true
                  },
                  "standings":true,
                  "players":false,
                  "top_scorers":false,
                  "top_assists":false,
                  "top_cards":false,
                  "injuries":false,
                  "predictions":true,
                  "odds":false
               }
            },
            {
               "year":2020,
               "start":"2019-03-21",
               "end":"2021-07-11",
               "current":true,
               "coverage":{
                  "fixtures":{
                     "events":true,
                     "lineups":true,
                     "statistics_fixtures":true,
                     "statistics_players":true
                  },
                  "standings":true,
                  "players":true,
                  "top_scorers":true,
                  "top_assists":true,
                  "top_cards":true,
                  "injuries":false,
                  "predictions":true,
                  "odds":false
               }
            }
         ]
      },
```

**Request:**

```
public class LeagueService : ILeagueService
{
    public async Task GetLeaguesFromApiAsync()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = new Uri("-"),
            Headers =
        {
            { "X-RapidAPI-Key", "-" },
            { "X-RapidAPI-Host", "-" },
        }};

        using var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(body);
    }
}
```

**Root class:**

```
public class Root
{
    public string Get { get; set; }
    public List<object> Parameters { get; set; }
    public List<object> Errors { get; set; }
    public int Results { get; set; }
    public Paging Paging { get; set; }
    public List<Response> Response { get; set; }
}
```

I have checked if the API returns values and it does. However, after deserialization all values in the result are null.

Comment: Any special setup on your `JsonSerializerSettings`?

Comment: By default, deserialization looks for case-sensitive property name matches between JSON and the target object properties. To change that behavior, set JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive to true (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/character-casing)

Comment: The JSON in the post looks incomplete, though.

Comment: Thank u richej. You were right.

Comment: You have `List<object>` properties. The items will be deserialized to JsonElement (if you are using System.Text.Json).